# Memory Usage full by the system R

Tags: r

I have just downloaded R and Rstudio version 4.2.0 to my work laptop. As soon as I open it the Memory usage is 93% and the majority of this is by the system. What does this mean and how do I reduce it as I am sure currently it will not be usable?

Attached image of the memory usage report and the result of running 'free unused r memory'

[result of R memory usage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnleR.png)

```
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 498226 26.7    1104412   59   638877 34.2
Vcells 774836  6.0    8388608   64  1630484 12.5
```

Comment: This doesn’t indicate an issue. Do you *have* any actual issues with memory usage? If not, ignore this: memory being used by the system is the normal state of affairs.

Comment: Ok, that's good news! I was just worried at the fact that it was red and going to cause issues when I wanted to run code. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Does that mean we can close the question?